# Exception when filtering on DateTime field in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm having a kind of bizzare issue while trying to filter results from Azure Table Storage by a DateTime field. I have two different queries for two diffferent tables with two different models. Both need to filter on a DateTime field but only one works, the other retuns an exception:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
StackTrace:
    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
```

The queries:

```
 var fromDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-14);
```

Working one:

```
 from entity in AnalyticsStorage.ConversionTable.CreateQuery<ConversionAnalyticsModel>()
 where entity.Date > fromDate
 select entity
```

Not Working:

```
 from entity in AnalyticsStorage.Table.CreateQuery<AnalyticsTableModel>()
 where entity.ResponseTime > fromDate
 select entity
```

I've made sure the the DateTime field is actually populated in the table. Commenting out the `where` makes the query run, though obviously that's not very useful.

Has anyone run into this? Are there gotachas in Azure Table Storage that I could be running into but can't see?

This is built against the current version of the Azure Storage DLL (3.0.3) and both queries are side by side in the same class, just in different methods.

Comment: kind of sounds like the managed wrapper isn't generating the correct HTTP queries.  Are you using the most recent Azure SDK?

Comment: Yes, this is built against Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 3.0.3. Which is part of my problem because I can't run it against dev storage because that hasn't been updated to v3 storage headers yet *face palm*

Comment: Can you post the code for your models as well? Regarding your dev storage comment, please update your emulator to 2.2.1 and your code will work against dev storage. More information on version 2.2.1 can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/01/16/windows-azure-storage-emulator-2-2-1-preview-release-with-support-for-2013-08-15-version.aspx.

Comment: I met similar error when worked with table storage with date property. My problem was, when I inserted entity I didn't specify date property value and assumed storage will give me a default value. But in .NET default date value is 0-0-0 0:0:0 while in storage service has a limitation that date property must be greater than 1970-1-1 0:0:0 or similar. So I got bad request error when I performed query. May not be your root cause but hope helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say I know why this is happening but after some time with Fiddler I figured out that it was using an anonymous type for the field name:

```
() gt datetime'2014-02-27T21:55:16.9605195Z'
```

Should be:

```
RequestTime gt datetime'2014-02-27T21:55:16.9605195Z'
```

Once I noticed this I wrote a query using the pre-LINQ syntax:

```
var query = new TableQuery<AnalyticsTableModel>().Where(
                TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                    "ResponseTime", 
                     QueryComparisons.GreaterThan,  
                     fromDate));
```

And this worked perfectly. So there seems to be a consistency issue with the current LINQ library that is causing it to not always map the field in the model to the field in the table. It could be that both `RequestTime` and `ResponseTime` are protected words to so my using their names is breaking the implementation without it properly warning me.